# Is it possible to change the DDV_MinMaxInt range at runtime?

Tags: mfc

Looking [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-validation-routines) it provides information about **Standard Dialog Data Validation Routines**.

I am interested in this one:

> [`DDV_MinMaxInt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-validation-routines#ddv_minmaxint) Verifies a given control value does not exceed a given `int` range.

Now, when you look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange-and-validation) it states:

> Dialog data validation (DDV) is an easy way to validate data entry in a dialog box. To take advantage of DDX and DDV in your dialog boxes, use the **Add Member Variable Wizard** to create the data members and set their data types and specify validation rules.

I realise that in the latest version of VS2017 the MFC wizard has been restricted and that it will be resolved in preview 4. That is a side issue.

I understand how it works in practice:

```
DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, m_iEventTypeMWB, 1, 4);
```

The thing is, based on another setting on the dialog, I have 4 different ranges. They all start at 1. At the moment I am not using DDV and I am manually testing, like this:

```
void CSpecialEventManagerDlg::OnCbnEditchangeComboboxexReminderInterval()
{
    BOOL bEnableOK = TRUE;

    UpdateData(TRUE);
    SetEventModified();

    m_iReminderInterval = static_cast<int>(GetDlgItemInt(IDC_COMBOBOXEX_REMINDER_INTERVAL, nullptr, FALSE));
    if (m_iReminderInterval < 1)
        bEnableOK = FALSE;
    else
    {
        // The interval can be four weeks (4)
        // The interval can be four weeks of days (28)
        // The interval can be four weeks of hours (672)
        // The interval can be four weeks of minutes (40320)
        if ((m_iReminderUnitType == CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::ReminderUnitType::Weeks && m_iReminderInterval > 4) ||
            (m_iReminderUnitType == CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::ReminderUnitType::Days && m_iReminderInterval > 28) ||
            (m_iReminderUnitType == CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::ReminderUnitType::Hours && m_iReminderInterval > 672) ||
            (m_iReminderUnitType == CCalendarSettingsGooglePage::ReminderUnitType::Minutes && m_iReminderInterval > 40320))
        {
            bEnableOK = FALSE;
        }
    }

    SetCorrectButtonStates();

    // Override - we can only apply the changes if the value is OK.
    m_btnApplyChanges.EnableWindow(bEnableOK);
}
```

It works fine. My question then is: Is it possible to change the DDV min/max range at runtime to a different set of values? This way I could just use DDV rather than my own tests.

## Update

I tried to fiddle with `DoDataExchange` to see if I could do it but it was showing a popup window at times when I was expecting it not to.

Here is another thing:

[image: Combo]

The above is really nice visually. If the user types a non-numeric value it shows a useful tooltip.

But with DDV, apart from showing a popup too many times, it doesn't even indicate which control it is relating to.

## Existing DoDataExchange

This is the existing DDX method (without any attempt at min / max):

```
void CSpecialEventManagerDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    //{{AFX_DATA_MAP(CSpecialEventManagerDlg)
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON_CLOSE, m_btnClose);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDCANCEL, m_btnCancel);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT_EVENT, m_editEvent);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_DTP_EVENT, m_dtpEvent);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST_EVENTS, m_lbEvents);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON_DELETE_EVENT, m_btnDeleteEvent);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON_ADD_EVENT, m_btnAddEvent);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON_APPLY, m_btnApplyChanges);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON_CANCEL_CHANGES, m_btnCancelChanges);
    DDX_DateTimeCtrl(pDX, IDC_DTP_EVENT, m_datEvent);
    DDX_Text(pDX, IDC_EDIT_EVENT, m_strEvent);
    //}}AFX_DATA_MAP
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBO_EVENT_LOCATION, m_dynEventLocation);
    DDX_CBString(pDX, IDC_COMBO_EVENT_LOCATION, m_strLocation);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, IDC_RADIO_SRR_INCLUDE_AS_MEETING, m_iEventTypeSRR);
    DDX_Radio(pDX, IDC_RADIO_SMR_INCLUDE_AS_MEETING, m_iEventTypeMWB);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_DTP_EVENT_START, m_dtEventStartTime);
    DDX_DateTimeCtrl(pDX, IDC_DTP_EVENT_START, m_datEventStartTime);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_DTP_EVENT_FINISH, m_dtEventFinishTime);
    DDX_DateTimeCtrl(pDX, IDC_DTP_EVENT_FINISH, m_datEventFinishTime);
    DDX_Check(pDX, IDC_CHECK_EVENT_ALL_DAY, m_bEventAllDay);
    DDX_Check(pDX, IDC_CHECK_SET_REMINDER, m_bSetReminder);
    DDX_CBIndex(pDX, IDC_COMBO_REMINDER_UNIT, m_iReminderUnitType);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBO_REMINDER_UNIT, m_cbReminderUnitType);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_COMBOBOXEX_REMINDER_INTERVAL, m_cbReminderInterval);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_STATIC_EVENT_START_TIME, m_lblEventStartTime);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_STATIC_EVENT_END_TIME, m_lblEventFinishTime);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK_EVENT_ALL_DAY, m_checkEventAllDay);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK_SET_REMINDER, m_checkSetReminder);
}
```

Comment: I've often found DDV to be too unflexible, so most of the time I just ignore it and do my own validation in OnChange handlers like you currently do or in `OnOK()`. What about your current solution do you not like and wish to solve using DDV?

Comment: @zett42 I suppose I felt that it would be nicer to have similar behaviour as when a letter was typed in the `CComboBoxEx` control. So, when the value was not in the range show the tooltip. However, since I support over 40 languages I did not want to do my own translations and thus hoped to use DDV. But I can leave it like it is.

Comment: This seems like it should be possible - there's an example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn026-ddx-and-ddv-routines that varies the age limit based on sex. What does your DoDataExchange routine look like?

Comment: @MercuryDime I have added the method to the question for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this in `DoDataExchange`:

```
DDX_CBIndex(pDX, IDC_COMBO_REMINDER_UNIT, m_iReminderUnitType);
DDX_CBIndex(pDX, IDC_COMBOBOXEX_REMINDER_INTERVAL, m_iReminderInterval);

if (m_iReminderUnitType == Weeks)
{
    DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, m_iReminderInterval, 1, 4);
}
else if (m_iReminderUnitType == Days)
{
    DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, m_iReminderInterval, 1, 28);
}
// etc
```

## Update (from user)

I adjusted my combo handler like this:

```
void CSpecialEventManagerDlg::OnCbnEditchangeComboboxexReminderInterval()
{
    m_iReminderInterval = static_cast<int>(GetDlgItemInt(IDC_COMBOBOXEX_REMINDER_INTERVAL, nullptr, FALSE));

    BOOL bEnableOK = UpdateData(TRUE);

    SetEventModified();
    SetCorrectButtonStates();

    m_btnApplyChanges.EnableWindow(bEnableOK);
}
```

The main thing was that I had to call `GetDlgItemInt` **before** the `UpdateData` call. Then, in `DoDataExchange`:

```
// Use DDV instead to validate the interval
DDV_MinMaxInt(pDX, m_iReminderInterval, 1, m_iMaxReminderInterval);
```

This works great because I already calculated `m_iMaxReminderInterval` when the user changed the interval **type**:

[image: DDV Feedback]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it to work. :) I was able to simplify it for my needs so I extended your answer a bit.